# Avoid Logged in users to access index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a ticketing website and I want to avoid users from opening `index.php` after they logged in. When they are logged in, they are automatically redirected to `dashboard.php`. Because my Login page is my `index.php` file and I want to customize it for login only. I want to write some code like below in PHP or jQuery or JavaScript:

```
<?php
    $call_user = $site_calls->call_user;
    if ($call_user <> 0){
        //redirect to ("dashboard.php");
    }
?>
```

If someone already logged in , they are redirected to `dashboard.php` whenever they want to access to `index.php` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Simplest code, working shown below. Set a session variable after login, check for that session variable in index.php, if its set, redirect to dashboard.php`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["user"]))  //change to your session variable
    {
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was an advantage to the JS solution. I also added an answer using the `header`.

Comment: yes i use script redirect because of this "header() must be called before any actual output is sent"  :)